# Where is Project Open Data data.xml format defined

Tags: metadata, ckan, opendata, dkan, dcat

I would like to convert a  dataset into Project Open Data data.xml format so that I can ingest in via the DKAN harvester. I know there is data.json format but prefer to use data.xml as the data is already XML and I am comfortable transforming it.

I can't seem to find where the data.xml schema/format is defined and would be grateful for pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The data.json file is created by [implementing](https://github.com/GetDKAN/dkan/blob/7.x-1.x/modules/dkan/open_data_schema_map_dkan/open_data_schema_map_dkan.features.inc#L1273) the [Open Data Schema Map](https://github.com/GetDKAN/open_data_schema_map) module in DKAN.

You have a couple of options:

1. Create a new endpoint at "/admin/config/services/odsm/add/api" and use XML as the output format and "Project Open Data v1.1" as the schema:

[image]

2. You can do the same thing in code using hook hook_open_data_schema_apis_defaults() that [Open Data Schema Map DKAN](https://github.com/GetDKAN/dkan/blob/7.x-1.x/modules/dkan/open_data_schema_map_dkan/open_data_schema_map_dkan.features.inc#L1273) uses. Copy the declaration for "data_json" in your own module and change the endpoint to "'endpoint' => 'data.xml'," and the format to xml.
3. You could use [hook_open_data_schema_map_results_alter](https://github.com/GetDKAN/open_data_schema_map/blob/7.x-2.x/open_data_schema_map.api.php#L96) to alter the schema to use "data.xml" and format to XML in a custom module.